# How to define a set of trees recursively?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion, trees

In particular, consider the set of integer-labelled binary trees (*T*). How could this set be defined in a recursive way from $\mathbb Z$ and *T* itself?

Examples:
$(-2, 1, (3, 1, 0)) \in T$
$(-1, (7, 2, 2), (3, 3, -1)) \in T$

Update: let's say that the empty tree is not considered.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is a binary tree, and if $a,b$ are some binary trees and $n$ is a node, then $(n,a,b)$ is a binary tree. here, a node is an integer

Comment: I was expecting more a Cartesian product version.

Comment: I don't see the point. the number of labels depends on the tree, hence you can't consider without precautions the direct product between $T$ and the set of integer sequences

Comment: If you want a simple answer, then just let $T_n$ be the $n^\text{th}$ tree in lexicographical ordering.  It's not very amenable to symbolic logic, but it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive definition for binary trees already could be

1. $() \in T$, where $()$ (the empty tuple) represents the empty tree
2. For $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $t_1, t_2 \in T$ we have $(k, t_1, t_2) \in T$

but it would not reproduce your intended specimens.

Those are included in this version:

1. $() \in T$
2. For $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $k \in T$
3. For $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $t_1, t_2 \in T \setminus \{ () \}$ we have 
   $(k, t_1, ()), (k, (), t_2), (k, t_1, t_2) \in T$

Update:

Without empty trees, one could only build trees where each node has either no or two sub trees:

1. For $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $k \in T$
2. For $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $t_1, t_2 \in T$ we have 
   $(k, t_1, t_2) \in T$

Comment: The motivation of the question was to dig into the possibilities of having a recursive set definition. 'Recursive' in the sense of finding the same object in the right and left sides of an expression. For example, your last proposal written in the manner $$T=\mathbb Z \times T \times T$$There's no such thing in sets definition, correct?

Comment: You could write it as $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq T \wedge \mathbb{Z}\times T \times T \subseteq T$, where the last relation features the sought $T$ on both sides.